# Parsing Ooxml using Open XML SDK

Tags: ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk, apps-for-office

I'm using [Javascript API for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185(v=office.1501401).aspx) to get ooxml of parts of the document using [Binding.getDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161073%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx). The result is that I have ooxml text which represent part of the document:

[image]

Now what I want is to alter this XML for example to put a table around the contents or to show a comment then save it back using [Binding.getDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161120%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx).
How can I use OpenOffice SDK to parse this xml to a document or a document part and do this processing?

I tried to use all the following:

```
var doc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document(ooxmlText);
//var part = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocPart(ooxmlText);
//var parts = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocParts(ooxmlText);
```

But I get back an error each time saying:

```
The XML has invalid content and cannot be constructed as an element.
```

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue? did you get any solution you want to share with me?